# How to use php pcntl_fork with thread?

Tags: php, multithreading, fork

I saw at, 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.posix-setsid.php
pcntl_fork() example at bottom. That code is working fine. can i combine it with php thread? http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php

```
<?php
    $pid = pcntl_fork(); // fork
    if ($pid < 0)
        exit;
    else if ($pid) // parent
        exit;
    else { // child

        $sid = posix_setsid();

        if ($sid < 0)
            exit;

        for($i = 0; $i <= 60; $i++) { // do something for 5 minutes
            sleep(5);
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but if you want to mix threading and forks randomly, you better read this before doing it: [Threads and fork(): think twice before mixing them](http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them) If you just want to detach from the controlling terminal and then start threads, (but not processes) that's most probably going to be fine. (Just replace the `for` part with the threading code.)

At any rate, it should be noted that writing PHP daemons that don't have memory leaks is extremely hard, but not impossible. Expect to spend a LOT of time on hunting down memory issues, especially if you are using complex class structures.

Also, some of PHP's extensions are **not thread safe**, especially if they execute some external binary. You may really want to think twice before doing this. I would also consider picking a different language.